# How do I get 48-bit LBA BIOS support?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, compatibility

Is there any freeware that allows me to check if my computer BIOS support 48-bit Logical Block Addressing, regarding hard drives?

I have two old Toshiba laptops (M40) that currently have 40GB disks and I would like to update to larger disk but I'm not sure that they will support it.

Answer (score 2):

Head over to 48bitlba.com and check out [HDInfo](http://www.48bitlba.com/hdinfo.htm):

### HDINFO Tool

Features:

- Provides information about ATA devices installed on a system.
- Can help determine whether 48-bit LBA device is properly connected to your system.
- Includes BIOS test for 48-bit LBA which will run on any system with any OS.
- Works with hard drives which have not been partitioned.
- Reports OS information you need to know for 48-bit LBA support.
- Provides information about various ATA modes useful to determine if BIOS has configured your hard drive for maximum performance.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt it supported it originally, it was sold just before 48 lba was implemented, but there may be a bios update that enables it. [Support shows only 2 bios revisions](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/modelContent.jsp?ct=DL&os=&category=&moid=1213732&rpn=PSM42U&modelFilter=M40-S4112TD&selCategory=2756709&selFamily=1073768663) and they don't mention 48bit upgrade.

If you do not want to buy HDInfo, you can test it by installing a 160gb or larger hard drive in the notebook and enter the bios, if it reports the correct size of the drive then it supports 48 lba.